# My progam crashes when using custom dialog

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying to make a custom dialog but am experiencing a problem. My app crashes when I push the button which shows the dialog.

Here is my code:

```
public class Cartas extends AppCompatActivity {

    Dialog myDialog;
    Button senmacho;
    Button cerrar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_cartas);

        senmacho = (Button) findViewById(R.id.senmacho);
        senmacho.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                senamacho();
            }
        });
    }

    public void senamacho(){
        myDialog = new Dialog(Cartas.this);
        myDialog.setContentView(R.layout.macho);
        myDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        cerrar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cerrar);
        cerrar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                myDialog.cancel();
            }
        });
        myDialog.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, please post your log.

Comment: Adding the output from the console when the crash occurs will help. The stack trace will show where in your code the crash is occuring.

Comment: the problem is here `cerrar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cerrar);`  the cerrar button is declare in  your Activity layout while it being use in your custom dialog layout. So if your button is in `R.layout.macho` already just change it to `Button cerrar = (Button) myDialog.findViewById(R.id.cerrar);`

Comment: post error logs

Comment: so, nullpointerexception, then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the line `cerrar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cerrar);` into `cerrar = (Button) myDialog.findViewById(R.id.cerrar);` or into `cerrar = myDialog.findViewById(R.id.cerrar);` might solve this issue . . .

Answer (score 0):

There is a very basic error.
You should follow the code below.

**Instead: of this:**

```
public void senamacho(){
    myDialog = new Dialog(Cartas.this);
    myDialog.setContentView(R.layout.macho);
    myDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    cerrar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cerrar);
    cerrar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            myDialog.cancel();
        }
    });
    myDialog.show();
}
```

**Use This**

```
public void senamacho(){
    myDialog = new Dialog(Cartas.this);
    myDialog.setContentView(R.layout.macho);
    myDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
   //modify the line bellow
    cerrar = (Button) myDialog.findViewById(R.id.cerrar);
    cerrar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            myDialog.cancel();
        }
    });
    myDialog.show();
}
```